# Angular ng-class is applied differently in 1.3.0 compared to 1.2.25

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I have a relatively large Angular application built on top of version 1.2.25. In my recent upgrade to 1.3.0 I discovered only one major issue which seems to change when html class changes are made to the DOM.

In this jsfiddle example, notice the watch that gets the size of the DOM element which is based off a class that another directive changes:
http://jsfiddle.net/travisgosselin/sx7jponj/1/
This example uses Angular 1.2.25.

```
 scope.$watch(function () {
        return {
            width: element.closest('.checkSize').width(),
            height: element.closest('.checkSize').height()
        };
    }, function (size) {
        scope.height = size.height;
    }, true);
```

Another jsfiddle that is exactly same but with Angular 1.3.0, you will notice that the watch does not fire the update since the class appears to be applied after the $watch has occurred, rendering no update to the size of the element.
http://jsfiddle.net/travisgosselin/t80segou/1/

```
scope.$watch(function () {
        return {
            width: element.closest('.checkSize').width(),
            height: element.closest('.checkSize').height()
        };
    }, function (size) {
        scope.height = size.height;
    }, true);
```

The idea behind this is to allow one of my directives to resize independently of whats happening in the other component.

In the Angular change log the only mildly related change I can see is that relating to ngAnimate. See breaking changes under 1.3.0-rc.5:
*The $animate CSS class API will always defer changes until the end of the next digest. This allows ngAnimate to coalesce class changes which occur over a short period of time into 1 or 2 DOM writes, rather than many. This prevents jank in browsers such as IE, and is generally a good thing.
If you find that your classes are not being immediately applied, be sure to invoke $digest().*

Any idea's how I can best modify this scenario to get the watch on the dom element size to fire? My only alternative at this point is using a series of events that are fired from many different locations that force the resize (pub/sub).

Comment: You can trigger a digest cycle after the one taking place when you're calling `changeSize()`. Add a `$timeout();` call at the end. Yep, I know, that's dirty…

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Blackhole. It seems like all workarounds in Angular start with "$timeout". I did try that in my application and it worked well - However you must pass a function to $timeout otherwise it will error out - so I had to pass an empty function making it even uglier. That being said, it was so simple, I used this as my work around with lots of comments. I really would like to understand how to tackle this scenario in Angular or if there is a bug here (I guess ideally I should not have structured my watch in the directive based on element size).

Comment: I'm also seeing a case where ng-class has a race condition and ultimately applies both old and new value to the dom when only one class should ever be applied.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, if you can include `ngAnimate` in your application.

`$animate.enabled(false, element)` -- Trigger this method inside the `changeclass` directive by passing element reference on which `ng-class` is applied

```
app.directive("changeClass", function ($animate) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        template: '<div><div ng-click="changeSize()">Change</div><div  ng-class="{ \'biggerSize\': biggerSize }" class="smallerSize checkSize"><div read-class></div></div></div>',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $animate.enabled(false, angular.element(element.children()[1]));
            scope.biggerSize = false;
            scope.changeSize = function () {
                scope.biggerSize = !scope.biggerSize;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t80segou/2/)

Comment: Thanks Vinay! Interestingly enough that workaround does seem to work. I have already implemented some other digest workarounds for the time being. Was hoping to get more of a direct answer on this one.